# CakePHP saving default 0 values

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-design, cakephp-1.3

Using CakePHP 1.3 I would like to save a `0` value for a field if nothing is written in the form field.
Best way is to do it in just MySQL but no success. I have tryed to set:

`Null`=`no` and `Default` = `0`; or `Null`=`yes` and `Default` = `0`;

Also both combinations combined with CakePHP Behavior which sets in `beforeSave` or `beforeValidate`:

`$model->data[$name][$field] = 0;`
or 
`unset($model->data[$name][$field]);`

also with:

`Null`=`yes` and `Default` = `0`; or `Null`=`yes` and `Default` = `NULL`;

Always the query is :

```
 INSERT INTO `table` (`zero_field`, `other_fields`) VALUES (NULL, 'other_data')
 or
 INSERT INTO `table` (`zero_field`, `other_fields`) VALUES ('', 'other_data')
```

And if `Null`=`no` getting an error: `Column 'zero_field' cannot be null`

Even if I unset the field I get the query with the field inside.

How should I save a `0` value in the databese if in the form it is not set or empty?

The `zero_field` is `int(11)`

Comment: What value does the zero field add to the system?  That is, what is it for?

Comment: How are you checking for empty?  How are you checking for NULL?

Comment: You really need to post your Cake code so we can see how you are performing the save.  You might be forcing it to save in a way that is not allowing a zero value to go through.  Also, if nothing is being saved to the database at all, maybe your Model validation is not set up to allow zero values for that field, and therefore the validation is failing and the save never happens.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set null = no, default = 0 for your field in database
2. Clear model cache files in app/tmp/cache/models/*
3. Be sure to use Model->create() before saving a new record so that it populates the new record to be saved with default values.
4. Save and Win.